# Installing jenkins locally

Tags: jenkins

I need to install Jenkins in my localhost(CentOS) and I tried issuing the procedures in the following link:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+RedHat+distributions

But it gives an error saying,

Resolving pkg.jenkins-ci.org... 63.246.20.93
Connecting to pkg.jenkins-ci.org|63.246.20.93|:80... failed: Connection refused.

Though, wget  http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org works fine.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you first download the war, and run **`java -jar jenkins.war`** to see if it works properly. It will start with the defaults.

If all is OK, maybe just wrap this with a script and configure it to run as a service.

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**: This is old, but worth mentioning that Jenkins has a formal Docker image you can use to quickly spin up a local instance for your tests. You can also mount a local directory into your container for persistence storage, which makes it a great option for your CI developments.

Quick test

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 jenkins
```

Better usage (with persistence storage)

```
docker run -d --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /local/dir:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

Point a browser to http://localhost:8080

See [official Github page](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker)