# Is it possible to deploy a node.js server to minikube from local jenkins when any commit done to github?

Tags: jenkins, minikube

I'm new to Jenkins...
Usually, we have a Jenkins CI/CD pipeline where it deploys code to kubernetes...

similarly, will I be able to have a deploy locally on minikube...?

if so pls guide me...

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes is running Deployments from Docker images, those images need to be hosted somewhere.

You can [deploy a registry server](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) and run it locally as a Docker container.

You can also follow this guide on how to [Use your local registry with Kubernetes](https://tortuemat.gitlab.io/blog/2018/03/18/kubernetes-with-local-registry/)

Please, read the Kubernetes documentation for [Images](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/).

Also, here is a StackOverflow question on how to [install Jenkins locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168143/installing-jenkins-locally)

If you have more questions, feel free to ask.